# Can't use a GridLength property in a custom Maui control

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I'm using a custom control I made for my MAUI project. In this control I have a property supposed to be of GridLength type, but it raises an error when I use it in the project : "Value cannot be null". I also tried declaring the property as string and do the manual cast to GridLength, but my Binding still doesn't work, and when I add a breakpoint inside my setter the debugger never reaches it.

The code of my custom property :

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty SpaceBetweenProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SpaceBetween), typeof(GridLength), typeof(IconButton), new GridLength(0.0));

[TypeConverter(typeof(GridLength))]
public GridLength SpaceBetween
{
    get => (GridLength)GetValue(SpaceBetweenProperty);
    set
    {
        SetGridColumns(value);
        SetValue(SpaceBetweenProperty, value);
    }
}

// ...

private void SetGridColumns(GridLength SpaceBetween)
{
    
    IBGrid.ColumnDefinitions = [
        new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Star),
        new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Auto),
        new ColumnDefinition(SpaceBetween),
        new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Auto),
        new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Star),
    ];
}
```

How I use it in my xaml file :

```xml
<utils:IconButton Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" IconMargin="10" SpaceBetween="10" LabelText="{Binding MyText}" FontSize="Large" ImageSource="road_sign_warning.svg" ButtonClicked="OnButtonClicked" IconSizeRequest="32" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
```

(Worth noting that before adding that custom property, and when none of my custom controls of this type have the SpaceBetween property, I have no compilation issue and the app runs without default.)

The error message I get : "Value cannot be null", with no error code at all.

[image: Error message : Value cannot be null]

Comment: Have you tried using `default(GridLength)` instead of `new GridLength(0.0)`, Also if you want to make any changes to your Control based on the Value you get in your setter, in your bindable property use its propertyChanged handler, basically this`SetGridColumns(value);`should be in a propertyChanged

Comment: I have first tried without any defaultValue specified, I was thinking it would just use the default value anyway, adding default(GridLength) manually didn't solve the problem either ; I also moved the method to the handler as you suggested, but I had the same problem.

Comment: Worth noting I also tried to change my propertyChanged so it doesn't depend on the object (just a `Console.WriteLine("Hello World"))`, but the error is still there.

Comment: And as soon as you remove this property the error goes away is it?

Comment: Wait I just realised, shouldn't `[TypeConverter(typeof(GridLength))]` be this `[TypeConverter(typeof(GridLengthTypeConverter))]`

Comment: Please try to use [TypeConverter（typeof（GridLengthTypeConverter））] for [GridLength Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlength?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead of [TypeConverter（typeof（GridLength））]

Comment: That was it, I was just specifying the wrong TypeConverter type ! If one of you want to write this down in an answer I can close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use GridLength Struct, the TypeConverter should be set to  `[TypeConverter（typeof（GridLengthTypeConverter））]`, like the following code:

```
[TypeConverter（typeof（GridLengthTypeConverter））]
public GridLength SpaceBetween
{
    get => (GridLength)GetValue(SpaceBetweenProperty);
    set
    {
        SetGridColumns(value);
        SetValue(SpaceBetweenProperty, value);
    }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to [GridLength Struct Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlength?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set space between rows and columns in Grid use `RowSpacing` and `ColumnSpacing` properties.

If your `SpaceBetween` property has another meaning, then make it of type `double` (or string for special cases)

Comment: I wanted to be able to set the space between two **specific** columns of my grid, not between the grid columns globally